# MySQL: bind-address 0.0.0.0 in my.cnf does not work?

Tags: mysql, my.cnf

I'm new to mysql.
I want to connect to mysql server using whatever ip I want.
I read that all I have to do is to add to my.cnf file the line bind-address = 0.0.0.0.
That's what I did.
I restarted mysql server and then I tested it from command line.

```
mysql -uroot -p'*password*' -h 127.0.0.1 --> Works
mysql -uroot -p'*password*' -h 192.168.2.4 (local ip address) --->
ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'root'@'mguru.lnx.gr' (using password: YES)
```

You can see below part of the section mysqld in my.cnf file

```
[mysqld]
user = mysql
port=3306
socket          = /opt/lampp/var/mysql/mysql.sock
skip-external-locking
key_buffer = 16M

max_allowed_packet = 1M

table_open_cache = 64

sort_buffer_size = 512K

net_buffer_length = 8K

read_buffer_size = 256K

read_rnd_buffer_size = 512K

myisam_sort_buffer_size = 8M

plugin_dir = /opt/lampp/lib/mysql/plugin/
#skip-networking
bind-address=0.0.0.0
```

Thank you in advance,
Nikos

Comment: Sorry i misread the whole question, maybe this can help you, as far as i know it is not possible to use multiple IP's, really it shouldn't be neccessary anyway. May i ask why you want to do such a thing?
http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/unix-linux-mysqld-server-bind-to-more-than-one-ip-address/

Answer (score 7):

The configuration option `bind-address` tells MySQL what interfaces to listen on.  By receiving the error `Access denied for user 'root'@'mguru.lnx.gr'` we can see that is actually working fine.

What you will need to do is modify MySQL's privilege system so that you are able to connect from `'mguru.lnx.gr'`.  The potentially confusing part of privileges in MySQL is that it is the combination of a username + the host.

This is covered in the MySQL manual [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/grant.html).